# Django cannot open downloaded zip file

Tags: python, django

I want to download a note with all attached files to a zip file in Django by clicking a button.

That's the view:

```
def download_note(request, pk):
note = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=pk)
file_path = f'notes/media/downloaded_notes/note{note.id}.txt'
notefiles = NoteFile.objects.filter(note=note)
urls = [f.file.url for f in notefiles]
if get_language() == 'en':
    content = f'Title: {note.title}, Author: {note.user}, Date: {note.add_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")}\n' \
               f'Category: {note.category}\n' \
               f'Note:\n{note.note_text}'
else:
    content = f'Tytuł: {note.title}, Autor: {note.user}, Data: {note.add_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")}\n' \
               f'Kategoria: {note.category}\n' \
               f'Notatka:\n{note.note_text}'

with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(content)

zip_file_path = f'notes/media/downloaded_notes/note{note.id}.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zipf:
    zipf.write(file_path, os.path.basename(file_path))
    media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT.replace('\\', '/')
    print(media_root)
    for url in urls:
        print(f'{media_root}{url[6:]}')
        #file_url = os.path.join(media_root, url[6:])
        #zipf.write(file_url, os.path.basename(url[6:]))
        file_name = os.path.basename(url)
        zipf.write(f'{media_root}{url[6:]}', file_name)

with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    response = FileResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="note{note.id}.zip"'


return response
```

When I click download button Chrome hangs for few seconds and then file is downloaded. But zip file in Downloads directory is not working. When I am trying to open it there is a message saying that the file's format is invalid or file is broken. But when I go to django project and to media/downloaded_notes/note70.zip everything works fine.

So I think an issue is in this fragment:

```
    with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    response = FileResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="note{note.id}.zip"'
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `FileResponse` expects a file-like object, not the file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please employ `HttpResponse` instead of `FileResponse`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="note{note.id}.zip"'

# You can also set the content length if you know it:
# response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(zip_file_path)

return response
```